# Retrieving data from firebase taking long time on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, ios10

I'm using firebase as my backend. Recently I got a strange issue in my app. When retrieving data from firebase it's taking so much time > 20 seconds. After investing so much time on this issue following is the clear description of the issue.

1. It's working fine on iOS9. Problem only with iOS 10 (that too on real device. Working fine on iOS 10 Simulator)
2. Working fine with sample created outside the project.
3. Working faster in staging environment where a number of users less. Problem with a real-time environment where a number of users are high.

Thanks in advance

**Note:** Please don't mark this as a duplicate. I went through many questions in stack overflow and not found a satisfying answer.

Comment: If you think this is related to the number of users on your project, you should [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. To be on topic here on Stack Overflow, you'll have to share the [minimum code that is needed reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen. I found answer

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found an answer to this scenario. It's all because of one single line.

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "\(BASE_URL)").keepSynced(true)
```

It's the reason for lagging in retrieving data.

Comment: almost useful.  Have you shown the problem line or the solution line?  As it stands, this doesn't tell anyone anything, other than the fact that you had a problem, solved, it, but left the question here as unanswered